# How to find a specific word in a MySQL table?

Tags: php, mysql

i want to find specific keyword in MySQL Table ....

The main code is:

```
if ($_REQUEST["keyword"]<>'') {
$search_string = "AND trainer like '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%' 
OR venue like '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%' 
OR session like '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%' 
OR course like '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%' 
OR category like '".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%'";    
} 
else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." 
WHERE id>0".$search_string;
}
```

**The problem is the code above shows same result for any word searched.** Any help of reference will be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the problem you're having exactly?  You show the code, but you don't explain what happens when you run it.  In what way does it fail?

Comment: like this `%$keyword%`

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your problem is that you're getting incorrect results, you can fix this with the following:

```
$search_string = " AND (trainer like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%' 
    OR venue like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%' 
    OR session like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%' 
    OR course like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%' 
    OR category like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%')";
```

Changes made:

1. Added brackets around your set of `OR` statements
2. Prepended the wildcard character to your search string, as well as the existing appended wildcard
3. Added a space before your `AND` so your resulting query doesn't end up containing `id>0AND`

**Edit:**

I thought I could help more by explaining what is going wrong.  Assuming someone searches for 'foo' and your table is called 'bar', your code will generate the following query:

```
SELECT
*
FROM
bar
WHERE
id>0AND
trainer like 'foo%'
OR venue like 'foo%'
OR session like 'foo%'
OR course like 'foo%'
OR category like 'foo%'
```

There are a couple of problems here:

1. You have combined your parts incorrectly so `AND` winds up right next to 'id>0', a space before `AND` fixes that problem.
2. You haven't wrapped your set of `OR` statements in brackets, so you end up with a query that asks for ANY of the conditions to be met (including `id > 0` *by itself*)
3. You have not prepended a wildcard character to the search string, meaning you will only find records that *start with* 'foo', and not records that *contain* 'foo' somewhere else.

The suggested changes above will fix these problems.

Comment: Sorry but the result is still the same.

Comment: @MOZ you'll need to post an example of the data in your table, and the results you're seeing.

Answer (score 0):

For whole specific word you need means you have to go through with double **%%** before and after the word

```
  if ($_REQUEST["keyword"]<>'') {
    $search_string = "AND trainer like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%'  
OR venue like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%' 
OR session like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%' 
OR course like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%' 
OR category like '%".mysql_real_escape_string($_REQUEST["keyword"])."%'";    
} 
else {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM ".$SETTINGS["data_table"]." 
WHERE id>0".$search_string;
```

}